# Probability that $k$ acute triangles can be formed

Tags: combinatorics

A stick is broken into $n$ pieces, with each breaking point chosen randomly and independently, with $m$ choose $k$ triangles being formed.

The probability that an acute triangle can be formed is $\ln(8)-2$, if we have $m$ choose $k$ triangles, what is the probability that exactly $k$ acute triangles can be formed?

Anything would help here, thanks!

Comment: Clarification:  You're assuming that only the subset of break sets are considered in which ${m \choose k}$ triangles *are in fact* formed?

Comment: Yes, that is correct.